# Eclipse RCP: don't refresh View when it is minimized

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, minimize

We have [View that shows file from Internet](https://github.com/satyagraha/gfm_viewer/blob/master/plugin/source/code/satyagraha/gfm/viewer/views/GfmView.java#L103)

```
public class GfmView extends ViewPart implements GfmListener {
```

How to know when View is minimized, so maybe there is no need to refresh View.

[#8 [optimization] Don't update View when it is minimized](https://github.com/satyagraha/gfm_viewer/issues/8)

[Documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/part/package-summary.html&resultof=%22ViewPart%22%20%22viewpart%22) doesn't [say](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/part/ViewPart.html) about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `org.eclipse.ui.IPartListener2` - Implementation to track the state of your view. This listener is called if your view will be minimized (or closed or hidden or ...)

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().addPartListener(<myPartListener>)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tom: I'm afraid it is not always that simple...

In Eclipse Juno (4.2), the IPartListener2 notifies about visible-hidden and also about activated-deactivated.

But this does not allow me to reliably determine when a ViewPart is minimized.

- visible-hidden is not triggered when minimizing or un-minimizing. It is only used for covering / uncovering windows.
- activated-deactivated is triggered when a window is minimized / un-minimized. But it is also triggered when the focus is changed to / from the window while the window is visible. (So actually this seems to be a focusGained-focusLost notification.)

Especially when a minimized window is restored (by pressing the icon with the stacked windows), there is no notification at all because the view does not gain the focus.

Bottom line: For IPartListener2, minimized windows are visible.

The question remains: How can I know when a view is minimized?